# How do I use clojure jdbc execute?

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, clojure

I'm struggling to get the `jdbc/execute!` function to commit any changes I make to my sqlite database.

For example,

```
user=> (jdbc/execute! sqlite-db ["insert into person (second_name) values ('Gandhi');"])
nil
```

`nil` is returned and the row is not inserted. However, I know the function is connecting to the database somehow because I can use an invalid table name and get an error:

```
user=> (jdbc/execute! sqlite-db ["insert into ABCDEFG (second_name) values ('Gandhi');"])

SQLException [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: ABCDEFG)  org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException (DB.java:383)
```

The jdbc library also includes a `jdbc/insert!` function, and I can insert correctly using this. However, I wanted to use the `execute!` function instead because in my application I use a more complex statement and I thought I would therefore supply a parameterized sql string.

Where am I going wrong using the `execute!` function?

Comment: Does execute! need to be inside a transaction in order to be committed?

Comment: It's happening in either case, but as PositiveLogic has mentioned I see now it's a known issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of this answer -> [Using execute! with no params to insert a row fails on SQLite](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/JDBC-65) <- is listed as still an open issue to be resolved in beta 0.3.0 of java.jdbc